# Computing scene luminance

Tags: cycles-render-engine, physics, light, lighting, pbr

I have a scene with materials and a light source with known luminous emittance. (for example, an interior scene, and clear day sunlight). I am looking to compute a physically accurate value for scene luminance (such as in this image from wikipedia).
[image]
Does anyone know how to set the scene, camera, and lighting up in such a way that the rendered pixel value is correlated to a real luminance value? The image can be processed in software outside of blender, but I must ensure that the pixel values make sense as they are being rendered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is "linear light" and a linear colour model.

**Setting either "Displace Device" to "None" or "View Transform" to "Raw" under "Color Management" in "Render Properties" seems to do the trick:**

[image] [image]

Also pay attention to "Save As Render" in the image save dialog box.

A render with four concentric and equally spaced rings with maximum roughness and zero specularity around a point light source produces peak colour values of around `[1.0, 0.29, 0.14, 0.09]`— Mostly what you'd expect from physically correct inverse-square behaviour, with some margin from clipping and sampling noise:

[image]

I saved the result as a 16-bit PNG, which should give you plenty of bit depth to play with. You may also want to try EXR or RGBE, depending on your use case— My image viewer for those formats seemed to apply an sRGB transform by default on display, but the data itself seems to be intact.

[image]

---

---

---

**Notes on interpreting the data:**

As the output data is in the form of dimensionless RGB values, if you want physical units then you'll have to calculate a conversion ratio based off of a known lamp power output, surface albedo, and distance.

In my example file, the innermost ring has an RGB peak of `1.0` with an albedo of `0.8` at a distance of `1m` from a point light source with `50W` of power output.

The `50W` of radiation at a distance of `1m` will be spread across a spherical shell of `4π(1m)²=12.57m²`, so incoming irradiance at that distance should be `50W/(12.57m²)=3.98W/m²`. Outgoing surface radiosity accounting for the `0.8` albedo should then be `3.98W/m²*0.8=3.18W/m²`. So that means `RGB(1.0)=3.18W/m²`, which in turn means that the radiosity at the other rings can be figured out by `RGB(0.29)=(0.29/1.0)*3.18W/m²=0.92W/m²`, etc.

It may be more sensible to establish a conversion ratio using a Sun lamp shining perpendicularly on a full-albedo, full-roughness, zero-fresnel dielectric (non-metallic) surface than a point lamp. The tooltip says that "Strength" maps directly to W/m².

You can probably also put that ratios or its multiple and/or reciprocal into the "Exposure" setting under Colour Management in order to havea 1:1 ratio between the RGB values and your physical unit of choice. Note that if RGB goes above 1.0, then you'll probably want to use either EXR or RGBE as your output file format.

**Always sample parts of your data by hand and check your numbers manually to see whether they make any sense, both based on your scene and relative to each other.** Digital colour management is frankly a mess, and there's a lot that can go wrong at pretty much any stage of the pipeline when you're trying to pull physical measurements out of artistic software.

**Further caveats:**

Note that this also still technically isn't the *luminance*, as it's just the *radiosity*. Luminance is a measure of perceived light as detected by human retinal cells, so you'd need to apply a [luminosity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminous_efficiency_function) to calculate it. You'll also need to make sure your render engine, file format, image viewer, etc aren't already accounting for the effects of the luminosity function.

From the fact that `RGB(1,1,1)` is white, we can also reason that even if interpreted as radiosity, the data is [scaled against sunlight's spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight#Spectral_composition_of_sunlight_at_Earth%27s_surface) rather than having a spectrally uniform power distribution.

Also note that Cycles and EEVEE run entirely in RGB, AFAIK, and not with continuous spectra. So if the spectra of your light sources and albedoes have a lot of spikes or valleys, the result will end up being further from physical accuracy.

Comment: Thanks that was super useful! Just another question to interpret the data coming from your scene: You used a 50 W white point light, and the first concentric ring's value color value is [1.0]. What does this tell me of the luminance from that point?

Comment: @gugiek Oh, good question! I suppose that doesn't actually tell you anything about the absolute luminance at that point, but you can figure out the absolute irradiance from `50W` and the `1m` distance, get the radiosity from that and the `0.8` albedo, then use that as your conversion ratio between RGB and SI units or whatever. Put that in the "Exposure" setting for a 1:1 mapping from RGB if you want. I added a lengthy section to my answer with an example, plus further caveats.